# indexOf not finding the variable on the array in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, jquery-animate, adobe

This script loads the data flawlessly from the text file to the myArrayofLines

```
function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
    var myArrayOfLines:Array = e.target.data.split(/\n/);
    for(var t:Object in myArrayOfLines)
  trace(t + " : " + myArrayOfLines[t]);

    trace(myArrayOfLines.indexOf("ace"));

    trace(myArrayOfLines[2]);
       }
```

Tracing myArrayOfLines[2] correctly displays "ace"

But using indexOf("ace") gives -1  , when it should be displaying 2

Help?

Here is code by Organis , but indexOf still giving -1

```
var aLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;

aLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
aLoader.load(new URLRequest("3letterwords.txt"));

function onLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    var aLines:Array = e.target.data.split(/\n/);

    for (var i:int = 0; i < aLines.length; i++)
    {
        trace(i + " : " + aLines[i]);
    }

   trace(aLines.indexOf("ace"));

    trace(aLines[2]);
       }
```

Comment: FYI, you can post your working code as an answer.  It doesn't really work with the site format to post the answer in the question body :\

Comment: So why didn't you just post the working code as an answer instead of removing it from my question and making it less helpful for others?

Comment: I figured you'd want to post it :)

Comment: If you click the "edited XY hours ago" link above my name, you can see the full edit history, including the revision that I rolled back, making it easy to just copy-paste the "working code" part into an anwser.

Comment: Now I am banned from asking questions?  What could I have done to deserve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because loading data is an asynchronous operation thus **onLoaded** event handler is executed **after** your **if** block. Basically, the execution order is following:

```
// 1
var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

// 2
myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

function onLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    // 5
    var myArrayOfLines:Array = e.target.data.split(/\n/);
    for(var t:Object in myArrayOfLines)
    trace(t + " : " + myArrayOfLines[t]);
}

// 3
myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest("3letterwords.txt"));

// 4
if ( myArrayOfLines.indexOf( word ) > -1 )
{
    // Success{

    clabelword.text = String(word) + String("good");    

}
```

That's why at point 4 the script does not have the data... **yet**.

The only reliable way to check the loaded data is to put the **if** block into the event handler or into any code that is executed **after** the event handler.

```
var aLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;

aLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
aLoader.load(new URLRequest("3letterwords.txt"));

function onLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    var aLines:Array = e.target.data.split(/[\r\t\s]*\n[\r\t\s\n]*/);

    for (var i:int = 0; i < aLines.length; i++)
    {
        trace(i + " : <" + aLines[i] + ">");
    }

    if (aLines.indexOf(word) > -1)
    {
        clabelword.text = word + "good";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, I had fixed the error by moving the code.. but now function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
    var myArrayOfLines:Array = e.target.data.split(/\n/);
 for(var t:Object in myArrayOfLines)
  trace(t + " : " + myArrayOfLines[t]);
 
 trace(myArrayOfLines.indexOf("ace"));
 
 trace(myArrayOfLines[2]);
       }    the above code correctly displays "ace" but when I search "ace" it results with -1

Comment: I updated my question, to make it easier on the eyes.

Comment: I used your code and still displays "ace" correctly for array[2]  but displays -1 when using indexOf

Comment: @MichaelRize Check if your `array[2]` is actually "ace" and not say " ace " (aka length and bytes).

Comment: @MichaelRize Now that pretty much depends on your data and on the result of the split. The result you get is possible, if, for example, the **newline** in that file is not just **\n** but **\r\n**, or there are extra spaces. I've updated **RegEx** in my answer (didn't check though) so that it splits by any whitespace chunk if there's **\n** in it, I think that will effectively trim the resulting lines.

Comment: @Organis  You are awesome.  The magic sequence you added (/[\r\t\s]*\n[\r\t\s\n]*/)   works!  You are a magician.